# In a SVM model, will results be viable when I decrease the test size to 0.06

Tags: machine-learning, svm, data-science

I used support vector machine model for classification using iris data set. I used train test split function to split the data-set into training and testing subsets.

when test_size was 0.3 the accuracy was low and then I decreased the size of testing subset to 0.06 and now the accuracy is 1 ie. 100%. obviously, the reason is clear, its because with testing data the amount of noise and fluctuations as decreases.

My question is- we want our model to be efficient but what value of test_size is acceptable for that. at what value of test_size will the result be viable.

here is some line of code from my program-

```
    from sklearn import datasets
    from sklearn import svm
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn import metrics

    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    X = iris.data[:, :2]
    y = iris.target
    C=1.0

    from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
    x_train, x_test, y_train ,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.06, random_state=4)

    svc = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=C).fit(x_train,y_train)
    y_pred = svc.predict(x_test)
    print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))

    lin_svc = svm.LinearSVC(C=C).fit(x_train,y_train)
    y_pred = lin_svc.predict(x_test)
    print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))

    rbf_svc = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.7, C=C).fit(x_train,y_train)
    y_pred =rbf_svc.predict(x_test)
    print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))

    poly_svc = svm.SVC(kernel='poly',degree=3, C=C).fit(x_train,y_train)
    y_pred = poly_svc.predict(x_test)
    print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

result is 100% accuracy for all 4 cases.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of tutorials on the iris dataset which can give you useful ideas. The general rule of thumb for the size of test set is between 20-30%; the results will *certainly* be no viable for a size of 6%, but you obviously know this already. Also, the question is off-topic here - it is better suited for the [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) sister site

Comment: In general 0.2 or 0.3 values used in `test_size` parameter.  If you are getting low accuracy with these, try to tune parameters or do some feature engineering. If you use test_size that low(0.06), your model is obviously overfitting.

Comment: You can do the cross-validation so that different data is chosen as test data in each fold, and then average the scores.